# Algorithm to evaluate pixels based on the minimum amount of line segments required to reach a certain point, while only crossing valid areas?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, line, region

Given a 2D pixel array where any pixel can be either 0 or 1, what algorithm would output a new 2D pixel array, where each pixel with a value of 1 would get a new value based on the minimum amount of line segments required to reach a specific "light source" pixel, while only crossing pixels that have an input value of 1? Input values of 0 would not change.

Example of input array, magenta cross represents the "light source" pixel:

https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/1/8/2a5f6dd0ebdc9c72115f9ce93af3337a-full.png

Output array with output values 1 and 2 (Photoshopped, not a pixel perfect image):

https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/1/8/0025709aaa826c26ee0a8e17476419cb-full.png

- Red region = 1 line segment away from source
- Yellow region = 2 line segments away from source
- White region = 3 or more line segments away from source

(The algorithm wouldn't stop at 3, it would continue until every pixel is evaluated.)

EDIT: I'm not sure whether StackOverflow is the right Stack Exchange site to post this in, if not please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Make your point of origin the origin of a polar coordinate system.  Convert the block corners to polar coordinates.

Now, treat your point source as a searchlight, sweeping from 0 to 2*PI.  The beam continues until it hits the frame edge or a black box.  This defines a polygon that you fill with magenta (1 line segment, direct lighting).

That's the easy part.  Now you get to repeat this for every pixel that lies on a magenta-white (1-0) boundary of the polygon.  This defines a finite set of secondary polygons; fill those with yellow (code 2).

Repeat this process with the yellow-white (2-0) boundaries to identify the `3` pixels; iterate until you run out of pixels.

In other paradigms, I've applied interval algebra to blocking segments (e.g. where one block partially shadows another), but I think that the polar polygon attack will get you to a solution in fewer hours of coding.